# Making snake in c but my snake is only moving every time a key is pressed (I want continuous movement)

Tags: c, game-development

I'm working on making the classic snake game in c. My program is working fine, other than the fact that when controlling the snake, it only moves when w/a/s/d are being pressed or held. For those who haven't played snake, the snake is supposed to move forward the whole time, and w/a/s/d simply change which direction the snake is facing.

Here is my code for the method responsible for moving the snake: let me know if you have any questions or if you need to see any of my either code to help, thank you! PS. using WSL, and using gcc as compiler

```
void snake()                        
{                           
makeFood();                     
pos head = { 10, 10 };                              
queue(head);                        
while( 1 )                      
    {                           
        int in = getch( );              
        if( in != ERR )                 
            key = in;                   
        switch( key )                   
        {                       
            
            case 'W':                   
            case 'w':                   
                head.y--;               
                break;
                
            case 'A':                   
            case 'a':                   
                head.x--;               
                break;
                                    
            case 'S':                   
            case 's':                   
                head.y++;               
                break;                  
                                    
            case 'D':                   
            case 'd':                   
                head.x++;               
                break;                  
                                    
                                
            case 'Q':                   
            case 'q':                   
                showMenu();             
                break;                  
                            
        }                       
        if( !inPlay( head ) )                  
            gameOver( );                
        else                        
            moveSnake( head );              
    }                           
    gameOver( );                    
}
```

Comment: If no key is being held and you want the snake to move forward every 0.5 seconds, then you will have to set some kind of timer that automatically calls a function in your program every 0.5 seconds, so that your program can take action whenever it is time to move the snake again. Unfortunately, plain ISO C does not provide such a timer. But most platforms offer such functionality as a platform-specific extension. Therefore, if you want your question to be answerable, you will have to specify to which platform (e.g. operating system and compiler) your question applies.

Comment: `getch` looks like a windows thing. Or, under linux/POSIX, it would be part of `ncurses`. However, under linux/POSIX, use `termios` and `tcgetattr` and `tcsetattr` to set the _kernel_ TTY driver into _raw_ mode. Then, use (e.g.) `char in; if (read(0,&in,1) == 1) key = in;` instead of `getch` Note that if you're using `ncurses`, the lib will do this for you.

Comment: If you are using Microsoft Windows, you will probably want a [waitable timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/waitable-timer-objects). However, this timer would not be fully compatible with `getch`, so you would have to use some other mechanism for waiting for the timer and waiting for keyboard input at the same time, such as [`WaitForMultipleObjects`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitformultipleobjects). However, I will not go into any further details until you have answered my question to which platform the question applies.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I'm using WSL (ubuntu)

Comment: @CraigEstey curses is written precisely for relieve people from doing such low-level things.

Comment: Read about the `timeout` function (type `man 3 timeout` in the terminal, or in the search field of your browser!). Calling `timeout(500)` once after initialising ncurses is a good start. `getch` will return `ERR` when the timeout expires. Later you will probably want to calculate the correct timeout value and call `timeout` before each `getch`.

Answer (score 0):

Emphasize: **Assuming OP looking for Unix/Posix solution - Linux, WSL, ...  Answer not relevant if looking for Window only solution. Same for curses.**

You have two items to deal with, all related to getch running against terminal input.

- By default, tty input is line oriented. It means that data will not be available to your program until the user clicks "enter". `stty -icanon` will address this.
- The 'getch' will use "blocking read", which means that if there is no input, the program will block for the next character. `stty -time 1` can cap the time (with 1/10 seconds precision).
- The standard terminal driver will echo input characters. Assuming program generating some graphic output, better to disable echo. `stty -echo`

If you input is coming from directly from a terminal, you can use the stty to change the behavior of the terminal. Remember to reset the setting, when your program exit, otherwise, they will carry forward for other commands that will interact with the terminal

```
( stty -icanon -echo min 0 time 1 ; myprog )
```

You can achieve the effect of 'stty' progmatically, if you use ioctl with the TCGETS and TCSETS - `man tty_ioctl` provide with details.

Comment: This is all wrong. `getch` is a part of `ncurses`. This library takes care of setting terminal modes so you don't do it yourself. Use the right `ncurses` call instead of this nonsense.

Comment: @n.m. Agreed. I've added a comment at the top highlighting this.

Comment: Just delete the answer. It is highly misleading. OP need not do any of this.

Comment: The answer is actually quite valuable for situations in which curses is not being used. As someone who recently had a very similar question, I would rather this answer remain even if it only covers one of the situations and doesn't necessarily answer the original question in the best way for the OP's situation.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem by using the `halfdelay()` function

Comment: It would help to show where exactly.